# Is there another way to proof that there can't be a bijection between reals and natural not using Cantor diagonal?

Tags: logic, set-theory

Is there another way to proof that there can't be a bijection between reals and natural not using Cantor diagonal?

I was wondering about diagonal arguments in general and paradoxes that don't use diagonal arguments. Then I was puzzled because I couldn't think another way to show that the cardinality of the reals isn't the same as the cardinality of naturals.

Comment: From [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question): "Your question should be clear without the title. After the title has drawn someone's attention to the question by giving a good description, its purpose is done. **The title is not the first sentence of your question**, so make sure that the question body does not rely on specific information in the title."

Comment: So, please, don't start your question with "The title say it all".

Comment: okay, I will edit it. thanks

Comment: May be there's a proof using [cofinality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cofinality), but I wouldn't bet on it.

Comment: Do you consider [the proof of Cantor's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_theorem#Proof) a Cantor diagonal? If not, you could prove $\Bbb R$ bijects with $\mathcal{P}(\Bbb N)$.

Comment: @J.G. The usual proof of Cantor's theorem is considered a ["diagonal" argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_diagonal_argument)

Comment: I asked because I didn't know what the OP really wanted, regardless of the classification in @jjagmath's link, but I'm glad it was shared because it pointed to [this earlier proof of Cantor's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_first_set_theory_article#Second_theorem) that should be appropriate. (Also, Rob Bland's is one of my favourites.)

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/46970/proofs-of-the-uncountability-of-the-reals

Comment: @J.G. , I didn't knew this earlier proof of Cantors theorem, thanks for the link, I will see it. But just to clarify, what I understand as a diagonal argument indeed is what the given link to wiki page says: given an $f: \mathbb{X} \to 2^\mathbb{X}$  surjective, the diagonal set is given by: $ x \in X \iff   x \not  \in f(x) $, and a diagonal argument would use this construction in some way.

Comment: I wrote an [answer here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/401608/113405) about the many proofs of the uncountablity of the interval $[0,1]$ (and as extension, of $ℝ$), the "diagonalization" argument is in fact Cantor's **third** proof, it is the most famous because of it's uniqueness and it's accessibility, but by no means it is the only proof

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way is through the use of measure theory. The measure of the unit interval $[0,1]$ is $1$, while the measure of any countable subset of the reals is $0$. This is enough to demonstrate that $[0,1]$ is uncountable, for if it were countable then its outer measure would have to be $0$.

The outer measure of a general subset $A \subset \mathbb R$ is defined as

$$m^*(A) = \inf \Big\{ \sum_i \ell(I_i) : A \subset \bigcup_i I_i\Big\}$$

where $(I_i)_i$ is any countable collection of intervals, $I_i = [a_i, b_i]$ for some reals $a_i < b_i$ for each $i$, and $\ell(I)$ is the *length* of the interval, defined as $\ell(a,b) = b - a$. What this definition means is: cover the set $A$ by (at most countably many) intervals, however you may like, and sum the lengths of those intervals. The (limiting) smallest possible total length is what the outer measure of $A$ is.

See [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Countable_Sets_Have_Measure_Zero) for a proof that a countable set has outer measure zero, and see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3985593/prove-the-unit-interval-has-outer-measure-1) for a proof that the unit interval $[0,1]$ has outer measure $1$.

Comment: Very interesting, I will look the details of this proofs. Do you think it can be generalized to every set as in Cantor theorem? Thank you.

Comment: I would not count on it, as Cantor's theorem is a very general statement about any set, and yet the measure function is only defined upon a suitable (measurable) space